# Cannot use certain variants with Mitsuba 3 Renderer

Tags: graphics, rendering, render, dllimport

As the title suggests, I cannot use variants such as llvm, cuda and the auto-differentiable variants with mitsuba 3.

I have checked that they are indeed variants using mitsuba.variants() as well as making sure they are listed in the config file, but when I try to run in jupyter notebook, I get the error that the LLVM dll cannot be found. scalar_rgb and scalar_spectral both work fine.

I built mitsuba directly from the repository, and so it should have included all the necessary dlls.

[image]

and below shows the enabled variants in the config file.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Do you have LLVM/CUDA installed? It seems to be necessary to install it manually: [LLVM](https://mitsuba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html#requirements)/[CUDA](https://mitsuba.readthedocs.io/en/latest/src/developer_guide/compiling.html#gpu-variants)

Additionally, CUDA also does not work with all graphics cards.

If you have LLVM/CUDA installed, please make sure that the paths are set correctly (see [here](https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/mitsuba3/issues/692)).

If this is still not solved, the [GitHub issues](https://github.com/mitsuba-renderer/mitsuba3/issues?q=is%3Aissue) are probably a better place for an answer than SO.